# Strange behavior of query in Pandas

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

I have downloaded the olist_geolocation_dataset from Kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/olistbr/brazilian-ecommerce#olist_geolocation_dataset.csv) and I am doing a first analysis.

My code is the following:

```
geolocation = pd.read_csv('olist_geolocation_dataset.csv')
df = geolocation.groupby(['geolocation_lat', 'geolocation_lng'], as_index = False)['geolocation_state'].count()
df.sort_values('geolocation_state', ascending = False).head()
```

[image]

```
geolocation.query('geolocation_lat == -23.495901')
```

[image]

[image]

My question is: why the query returns an empty dataframe given that the value passed in the filtering condition exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is value is float, so because precision problems, need [`numpy.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = geolocation[np.isclose(geolocation['geolocation_lat'], -23.495901)]
print (out.head())
       geolocation_zip_code_prefix  geolocation_lat  geolocation_lng  \
19112                         2020       -23.495993       -46.635616   
19118                         2020       -23.495960       -46.634081   
19129                         2020       -23.495861       -46.636183   
19161                         2044       -23.495681       -46.618947   
19167                         2084       -23.495675       -46.599478   

      geolocation_city geolocation_state  
19112        sao paulo                SP  
19118        sao paulo                SP  
19129        sao paulo                SP  
19161        sao paulo                SP  
19167        sao paulo                SP
```